# How to get a quick launch of a heavy event animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to start the animation immediately after clicking the button.
This is obtained if the code inside the function is simple. If the code is heavy, the animation starts with a long delay.
Please tell me that I can try or read on this topic.

I use bootstrap button animation in the following way:

```
$( '#button' ).click( function()
{

    $( '#button' ).addClass( '_loading_' );

    /*
    //very large code
    */

    $( '#button' ).removeClass( '_loading_' );

} );
```

Comment: Well, short of optimizing (and sharing a sample of) your "very large code", there's nothing you can really do to speed it up.

Comment: What do you mean by very large code? is it asynchronous?

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to start the animation first, then the "large code". I do not have the opportunity to change the "large code", so I don’t cite it.

Comment: "Very large code" is fully synchronous.

Comment: "animation starts with a long delay" - really? I just checked this case at jsfiddle and it turns out that animation just cannot be started when synchronous JS computations are going on in current thread. I think you can just show user something like "loading" without animation our use GIF, or if you really wanna show the animatio then use worker to make him do all the job while the main thread just waits for the worker and therefore able to render the animation.

И кстати русский стэк оверфлоу вполне себе адекватный и живой, там тоже можно задавать вопросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, I solved the problem. I would be happy if you tell me the more compact solutions.

```
new Promise(function (resolve)
{   
    new Promise(function (resolve)
    {   
            $( '#button' ).addClass( '_loading_' );
            resolve(1);
    } ).then(function (value)
    {

        /*
        //very large code
        */

    } );
    resolve(1);

} ).then(function (value)
{
    setTimeout( function()
    {
        $( '#button' ).removeClass( '_loading_' );
    },100 );
} );
```